# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4n^2+26n+34}{n^4+10n^3+35n^2+50n+24}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

serie is convergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4n^2+26n+34}{n^4+10n^3+35n^2+50n+24}$$

Factor: $$\frac{4n^2+26n+34}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}$$

What test can i Use?

Comment: Limit comparison with $1/n^2$.

Comment: How could i calcule the sum?

Answer (score 4):

Simply note that

$$\frac{4n^2+26n+34}{n^4+10n^3+35n^2+50n+24}\sim \frac4{n^2}$$

then refer to limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$ which converges.

Comment: yes,,, thanks .

Comment: @MathNewC Note that $$\frac{\frac{4n^2+26n+34}{n^4+10n^3+35n^2+50n+24}}{\frac1{n^2}}\to 4$$ and in any case the limit comparison test for convergence holds also when the limit is equal to 0.

Comment: How i Could find the sum?

Comment: im sorry @gimusi, yes, is 4

Comment: @MathNewC No, the sum is not 4 (or if somehow it is, the above calculation doesn't show it.)  However, if you want to know how to calculate the sum, you should ask another question.

Comment: @saulspatz The 4 was referred to the limit!

Comment: @gimusi Is there a missing comment, then?  I thought "I'm sorry, yes is 4" is a continuation of "How i could find the sum?"

Comment: @saulspatz Yes there was a comment deleted on that!

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{4 n^2+26 n+34}{(n+1) (n+2) (n+3) (n+4)} = \frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{4}{n+3}+\frac{1}{n+4}+\frac{2}{n+1}
$$

Then

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4 n^2+26 n+34}{(n+1) (n+2) (n+3) (n+4)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-4\sum_{k=4}^{n}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=5}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)-4\frac{1}{4} = \frac{7}{4}
$$

Comment: Nice, but you should use partial sums rather than summing divergent series.

Comment: No problem. I will fix it

Comment: This looks like a nice Extra Credit problem for students....+1